# How to use multiple items in a list at once - python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list:

```
mylist = [
"hello", "my", "name", "is", "frank", "and", "it", "is", "great", "to", "be", "here", "in", "this", "great", "country"

]
```

and am using

```
for i in range(0,len(mylist)):
    print(mylist[i])
```

to print out each item and it works as it prints out every word in a new line.

What I would like to do is to be able to treat multiple words in the list as one by changing the value of a variable `k`:

i.e I would like to instead of it outputting

```
hello                                                                                                                   
my                                                                                                                      
name                                                                                                                    
is                                                                                                                      
frank                                                                                                                   
and                                                                                                                     
it                                                                                                                      
is                                                                                                                      
great                                                                                                                   
to                                                                                                                      
be                                                                                                                      
here                                                                                                                    
in                                                                                                                      
this                                                                                                                    
great                                                                                                                   
country
```

I would like to if `k = 2` to output

```
hello my                                                                                                                      
name is                                                                                                                      
frank and                                                                                                                     
it is                                                                                                                      
great to                                                                                                                      
be here                                                                                                                    
in this                                                                                                                    
great country
```

should there be an odd number of items in the list, the last word should be alone in a line

if `k = 3` then there should be 3 words in a line

Is there any way to do this

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [this chunking recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/312464/9209546):

```
def chunks(L, n):
    """Yield successive n-sized chunks from L."""
    for i in range(0, len(L), n):
        yield L[i:i + n]
```

Then iterate with [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) or use sequence unpacking with the `sep` argument of [`print`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print):

```
for i in chunks(mylist, 2):
    print(' '.join(i))
    # alternatively, unpack and use sep argument:
    # print(*i, sep=' ')

# hello my
# name is
# frank and
# it is
# great to
# be here
# in this
# great country
```